# _stprintf() read only first char in C++ and MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a text edit control in my MFC application in C++ and I'm trying to read the text written in the control to write a file on my hard disk.

The problem is that it just read the first character and not the entire string.

```
 tchar fname[100];   
 _stprintf(fname, _T("%Sfile-%d.bmp"), pDoc->swap_text, swap);
save_image_uncompressed( (const unsigned char*) pDoc->image[idx], fname, pDoc->m_buf[idx].lpbmi[frm_idx]->bmiHeader.biHeight,
                        pDoc->m_buf[idx].lpbmi[frm_idx]->bmiHeader.biWidth,
                        pDoc->m_buf[idx].lpbmi[frm_idx]->bmiHeader.biWidth*3,
                        0);
```

For example, if in the edit control there is written: **name_of_directory/**, then it reads: "**n**file-1.bmp" which is the first character of name_of_directory/ string.

I tried to use

```
_stprintf(fname, _T("%Sfile-%d.bmp"), pDoc->swap_text.GetString(), swap);
```

but I have the same problem.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Shouldn't it be lowercase `s`? I mean in `%s`

Comment: Yes, i was too stupid to not notice it! Thank you, now it works.
I've spent too much hours to code during last days and now i'm almost dead.

Comment: I know the feeling ;)

Comment: What is the type of `swap_text` ? I ask because the VC-runtime handling of `%S` is to handle opposite char-width of whatever the TCHAR is defined to be. In a Unicode build, the `_T()` macros and `t` functions handle wide-chars, and `%S` expects a **narrow** string. The opposite is true when unicode is not being used (functions and macros use narrow strings, `%S` handles **wide** strings). As written, if you're building with unicode and `swap_text` is *not* a narrow string, it will only print the first char.

Comment: @WhozCraig: yes, i was using the narrow string and then I changed the format and I forgot to come back to lowercase s. Thank you for your help, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using the wrong format code:

```
_stprintf(fname, _T("%sfile-%d.bmp"), ...)
//                   ^^
```

You should use `%s` (lowercase) instead of `%S` (uppercase).